# How can I restore that very files set from my Git repo?

Tags: git, git-checkout

My case is top simple. I work alone (no team and I don't use GitHub / Bitbucket)

I just want to save in my local project Git repo all stages of my job.

I looked through a dozen of tutorials and everyone advises `git checkout 234abc7` to return to that particular commit. I do this to restore a file set from yesterday and I see in my GitBash not staged changes and untracked files, but physically all the files in my working directory remain the same. No changes to the past stage.

Of course, `git reset --hard` does work, but I want to save in my Git repo next commits as well so that tomorrow I could return to today's set of files in my working directory.

Comment: Can you attach a demo example to your post what exactly your concern is ?

Comment: Is the file you want to revert to a previous state tracked in your Git repo at all? If you forgot to `git add` it ever, Git has no record of the file's past content. (`git reset --hard` wouldn't work in that case either, though.)

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, especially the part: "that very files set from". Could you please rephrase your question? The description gives some hints, but it's difficult to understand your exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use branches or tags for this

Let's say you want to go back to specific commit and work on it:

- create tag using `git tag feature-a-is-working`
- use `git reset --hard SHA1`
- commit your new changes

Answer (score -1):

Well, das-g has given me a hint. - In fact I haven't added changes to repo and tried to succeed in checkout the last commit. - All is working now as it should. - Sorry, Git, - I was wrong :)